My FastAPI wont connect to my database when deploying with Render
I've tried to deploy my FastAPI code using Render, but I get errors when I try to send a POST request, stating that the database failed to connect. I have executed my FastAPI code using the terminal, and it connects to the database fine when I send a POST request. This is my first time using Render, so I am unfamiliar with how it works. I am currently using this as my start command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
Here is the code:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr, Field
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, OAuth2PasswordBearer
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., min_length=1) # requires name length of at least 1
    email: EmailStr
    password: str

class Login(BaseModel):
   email: EmailStr
   password: str

class Token(BaseModel):
   access_token: str
   token_type: str

class TokenData(BaseModel):
   email: EmailStr

# password hashing setup
pwd_cxt = CryptContext(schemes = ["bcrypt"], deprecated = "auto")

# hashing functions
class Hash():
    @staticmethod
    # Accepts password(str) and returns hashed password(str)
    def bcrypt(password:str) -> str:
        return pwd_cxt.hash(password)
    
    @staticmethod
    # Accepts plaintext password, hashed password, and returns bool for verification
    def verify(hashed: str, plain: str) -> bool:
        return pwd_cxt.verify(plain, hashed)
    
# token setup
SECRET_KEY = "secret key" 
ALGORITHM = "numbers"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30 

# Ceate JWT token
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta = None):
    to_encode = data.copy() # copy input data
    if expires_delta: # set expiration time
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes = ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
        to_encode.update({"exp": expire}) # update expiration time 
        return jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm = ALGORITHM) # encode token


def verify_token(token:str,credentials_exception: HTTPException):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        email: EmailStr = payload.get("sub")
        if email is None: # exception if no username
            raise credentials_exception
        return TokenData(email=email) # return TokenData instance
    except JWTError: # exception if token invalid/expired
        raise credentials_exception

# Users post credentials to the /login endpoint to obtain access token
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")

#checks if token is valid to return user 
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)) -> TokenData:
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail= "Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}
    )
    return verify_token(token, credentials_exception)


app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# MongoDB Connection
mongodb_uri = '<my_mongoDB_uri>'
client = AsyncIOMotorClient(mongodb_uri)
database = client["Cluster"]
users = database["Collection"]


@app.post('/register')
async def create_user(request: User):
    # check if email already in use
    existing_user = await users.find_one({"email": request.email})
    if existing_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")

    # hash the password
    hashed_pass = Hash.bcrypt(request.password)

    # create User object
    user_object = dict(request)
    user_object["password"] = hashed_pass

    # Insert the new user into the database
    result = await users.insert_one(user_object)
    if result.inserted_id:
        return {"res": "created"}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="User registration failed")

@app.post('/login')
async def login(request: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    # find user with given email
    user = await users.find_one({"email": request.username})
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No user found with this email")

    # checks given password is correct
    if not Hash.verify(user["password"], request.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Incorrect email or password")
    # creates access token
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": user["email"]})
    
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

this is my error:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 673d3b500f19ce930ab7ddcf, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>
I've tried changing the start command and it resulted in the same thing.

Where are you hosting your database? It looks like your app is trying to connect to localhost, which obviously won't work.

Yes my database is on a localhost. Will that not work with Render? If I can't use Render to host the localhost database, can you provide me with a service that wil?
